# npm start not working | Not Loading React Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

`npm start` command not progressing after below point -

[image]

Application is not getting loaded due to this.

Below is package.json -

```json
{
  "name": "reacttest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.1",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.33",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try running this in the command prompt instead of powershell. I think the syntax to run two commands in sequence is different in powershell (though not sure what it is)

Comment: @apokryfos - Stucking at same point on console also

Answer (score 1):

**Windows (cmd.exe)**

```
set HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

**Windows (Powershell)**

```
($env:HTTPS = "true") -and (npm start)
```

**Linux, macOS (Bash)**

```
HTTPS=true npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

add variable in .env

```
 REACT_APP_HTTPS = true
```

and in script

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ....
}
```

then run npm start and see.